# USRP N210 connection

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox

I am trying to set up OpenBTS on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have built the master version of RangeNetworks script. Since the transceiver did not start, I tried to check whether the USRP N210 board was even being detected by the system:

This is the actual IP address of the device and ping works fine with this IP address, however, uhd_find_devices does not find any devices attached.

I have tried disabling any firewall (sudo ufw disable).

Answer (score 0):

For first, make sure **uhd drivers** are installed. If not already installed, hit the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libuhd-dev libuhd003 uhd-host
```

Then hit

```
uhd_find_devices
```

If the USRP is not found yet, hit the following for **update firmware** with default images:

```
uhd_images_downloader
uhd_image_loader --args="type=usrp2,addr=<IP address>"
```

At the end of the procedure, your USRP is reachable at default ip. Then run

```
uhd_find_devices
```

to check if the USRP is found.